# Site isn't loading, all I'm seeing are these Sql Server errors being caught & logged

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Background: we moved from Sql Server 2005 to Sql Server 2008 R2. This application is deployed to 4 web servers. Only one of them is causing trouble. Only (maybe) 1 in 10 times the page will load, otherwise nothing gets returned at all, as in a completely empty response

This is the first error caught

```
Error Message: An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server.  When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider

Stack Trace:    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.SqlStateConnection..ctor(SqlPartitionInfo sqlPartitionInfo)
```

this is the second one:

```
Error Message: An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server.  When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider

Stack Trace:    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.SqlStateConnection..ctor(SqlPartitionInfo sqlPartitionInfo)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.SqlStateConnection..ctor(SqlPartitionInfo sqlPartitionInfo)
```

I have no idea what the problem could be.

Comment: Have you checked to see if SQL Server Remote Connections is set to Allow?

Comment: yeah our sys admin gave all that stuff a once-over..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the call stack, it appears that perhaps one of your web.config files for the application is configured to use ASP.NET session state storage inside SQL Server. You say it is deployed to 4 servers. I would check all of the web.config files and ensure that you are not using in-proc session state on 3 for example, and then trying to use session state storage in SQL on the other.

Comment: As part of the migration from Sql Server 2005 --> 2008 R2, whoever did the migration forgot to add the AspState database. That's all it was

Answer (score 2):

Your first error started with...

> Error Message: An error has occurred
>   while establishing a connection to the
>   server.  When connecting to **SQL
>   Server 2005**

Bearing in mind you said you've upgraded to SQL Server 2008 R2, it looks like something is still referencing the old SQL Server 2005 instance? I would check your asp.net application to make sure it has the correct connection setting for your new SQL Server.

On SQL Server, you could check to make sure SQL Server allow Remote Connections.